# how to know execution time of a background task in Linux

Tags: linux, operating-systems, raid

I am working with software raid in Linux. When I start the recovery of a raid array after a disk failure this task happens in background. `/proc/mdstat` should show the estimated time of recovery but it is not correct. In my case `/proc/mdstat` was showing estimated 15 hours but the recovery was done in around 10 hours. Is there a way to know exact time of execution of recovery daemon?

Comment: How about the kernel log? Otherwise, dmesg shows log messages (printk's) which include (depending on your kernel config) the number of seconds since kernel bootup.

Comment: @Friek sorry but i couldn't see timing information with dmesg.it is only showing log messages. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a simple script in the background that checks for the "rebuilding status" and dumps the time it's been waiting:

```
tick=$(date +%s)
while [ -n "$(cat /proc/mdstat | grep 'rebuilding')" ]; do
    sleep 10
done
tock=$(date +%s)
echo $(($tock-$tick))
```

`mdadm` also has a `--monitor` option that will sendmail when events are raised.  I've never used it, but it may be worth looking into since a completed rebuild may qualify as a noteworthy event.

Comment: thanks. both script and --monitor option worked for me . --monitor option is quiet sophisticated as it can e-mail on the state change of array.